# Can't access device sensors using nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm trying to listen on Gyroscope event in a `nuxtjs` app.

I have read about the sensor API, and tried to use it in the following way:

```js
mounted () {
    this.gyroscope = new Gyroscope({ frequency: 60 })
    this.gyroscope.addEventListener('reading', this.gyro_event)
    this.gyroscope.start()
}
```

where `this.gyro_event` is:

```js
gyro_event (e) {
    if (this.sensorData.time.length < 6000) {
        this.sensorData.time.push(this.gyroscope.time)
        this.sensorData.x.push(this.gyroscope.x)
        this.sensorData.y.push(this.gyroscope.y)
        this.sensorData.z.push(this.gyroscope.z)
    }
}
```

When running with `npm run dev` I get no errors. I also don't get any readings, but that's because my laptop doesn't have a gyro.

When running in production (serving the result of `npm run generate`) I get the following error:

[image: reference error]

**NOTE**: I had similar errors in development mode when trying to initialize the `Gyroscope` object prior to mounting (i.e. in the `created` or `data` hooks).

I also know that there are some other ways to access sensors (e.g. `ondeviceorientation` event), but I'm not sure what are the differences and which works best with `nuxt`/`vue`, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was caused by browsing via `http` and not `https`.